# Column changing numeric values to scientific notation by default

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

In sql server, I am trying to select insert data from one table into another. The code reads as:

```
Insert into TABLE2 (
Id, document_id
) select id, document_id from TABLE1
```

These two tables are basically identical. The document id field is in nvarchar50 since we will occasionally get values with a letter in them.

How can i get these to insert as numeric values, instead of scientific notation?

Thank you!

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: If formatting the excel as a number corrected it, what's the new / current issue? Save the excel as a csv woudl be another way

Comment: Im not inserting the excel file into table2. The excel file is initially loaded into table1, some manipulations are run, and then the end result is inserted into table2. Removed that portion to decrease confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume the columns in `table1` are of some `varchar` variant and hold the numbers in scientific notation. You can try to convert them to `real` (and if necessary to some other numeric or `varchar` variant form there).

```
INSERT INTO table2
            (id,
             document_id)
            SELECT convert(real, id),
                   convert(real, document_id)
                   FROM table1;
```

Comment: They are nvarchar50, but Table1 holds the numeric values. Those values are then converted to scientific when I insert from table1 into table2. I want to retain the numerical value upon insert. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Excel issue, where Excel treats the document id as a number instead as a text. The number formatting of Excel can potentially destroy information, as the same number can be represented in different ways. E.g. what was the original format of `500.2`? Was it `0500.200`, `000000000500.20` or something else? Also, Excel might even drop decimals, e.g. "5023423423423450" is displayed as "5.02342E+15". There is no way to restore this information in SQL.

You must handle this in Excel by either

- entering the document id with a leading apostrophe (`'`) to tell Excel not to interpret it in some way

or by

- formatting the document fields as `Text` **before** entering the document id.